# Javascript clicks are stacking

Tags: jquery

I have recently decided to revisit a past project of mine; a todo app. This app allows you to do the following:

1. input todo items
2. delete todo items
3. edit todo items

Before now, there was no confirmation before an item was deleted or edited. I have recently added those confirmations, to prevent accidental deletion or editing. I have also reworked my code a bit. Everything works as expected, except when multiple clicks are done.

Example : let's say I have 5 items on my todo list, but I need to edit 1 item and delete another. This means 2 clicks have to happen, Alt-click to edit and Shift-click to remove the other item. As expected I get my confirmation (once) to make the changes (edit) to the first item. Then when I go to delete the todo item that needs to be deleted, I get 2 confirmations for deletion.

I am using `$(document).on('click', el, () => { /* code here */ });` for my click event listener. I know that I can use `.one()` instead of `.on()` to prevent the clicks from stacking. However, this breaks the ability to perform multiple actions without page refresh. Having to do a page refresh after each action is not feasible.

HTML

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="container">
            <header>
                                <div id="title">Todo List</div>
            </header>
            <nav>
                
            </nav>
            <aside>
                <input id="todo" type="text" placeholder="Add new items here." />
            </aside>
            <main> 
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- incomplete todo -->
                    <div id="todo-incomplete"></div>
                </div>                            
                <div id="todo-notices"></div>
                <div id="todo-notes">   
                    <p class="text-info">Edit Item - Windows: Alt-click; Mac: Option-click</p>
                    <p class="text-info">Delete Item - Shift-click</p>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <div id="copyright"></div>
                <div id="page-load"></div>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

js / jQuery

```js
function checkTodos() {
    var list = JSON.parse(localStorage['todo-list']);
    if (list.length == 0) {
        $('#notices').html(`<div class='card'>No list items exist yet. Use the input box on the left to add items.</div>`);
    } else {
        let html = "";
        list.forEach((todo, index) => {
            html += `<div id='item-${index}' class='card' data-index='${index}'>${todo}</div>`;
        });
        $("#todo-incomplete").html(html);
        $('#notices').empty();
    }
}

function updateTodos(list) {
    $('#todo').val('');
    localStorage.setItem('todo-list', JSON.stringify(list));
    // each time we update the list, we need to display the updated list
    checkTodos();
}

function doConfirm(type = 'delete') {
    let message = type == 'delete' ? 'Do you confirm todo item deletion?' : 'Do you confirm todo item editing?';
    if (confirm(message)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
    let list;

    /* Gather info from the local storage database */
    if (localStorage) {
        list = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('todo-list') ? JSON.parse(localStorage['todo-list']) : [];
    }

    /* todo : display */
    checkTodos();

    /* todo : input */
    $(document).on('keydown', '#todo', (event) => {
        if (event.which === 13 && $(event.target).val() != "") {
            list.push($(event.target).val());
            updateTodos(list);
        }
    });
    /* todo : click events */
    $(document).on('click', '#todo-incomplete > .card', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        /**
         * BELOW IS WHERE ALL THE PROBLEMS WITH STACKING CLICKS COME INTO PLAY
         */

        if (event.shiftKey) {        // delete todo item
            if (doConfirm()) {
                list.splice($(event.target).attr('data-index'), 1);
                updateTodos(list);
            }
        } else if (event.altKey) {   // edit todo item
            $(event.target).attr('contenteditable', true);
            $(document).on('keydown', event.target, (e) => {
                if (e.which === 13 && doConfirm('edit')) {
                    $(event.target).removeAttr('contenteditable');
                    list[$(event.target).attr('data-index')] = $(event.target).html();
                    updateTodos(list);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // we do nothing.... yet!
            console.log(event.which);
        }
    });
});
```

- added current html that is paired with the js. Keep in mind this is a work in progress.
- I am using jquery version 3.6.4

Comment: Can you please add all relevant code to the question so we can see a working example. It's hard to diagnose something without seeing the actual behaviour.

Comment: *Offtopic*: instead of  `$("#todo-incomplete").empty().append(html);` use `$("#todo-incomplete").html(html);`

Comment: Adding a `keydown` event listener inside a `click` listener is probably the cause, as a general rule, don't add event listeners inside the result of another event listener.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the js that you see is the entire script. I have a very basic html layout and css to style the page. But if it helps I will add the html and css.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan agreed and fixed.

Comment: @DBS I am no master of jquery / js, so should I approach it? My current script looks for shift key press + mouse left click to delete items, also alt key press + left mouse click to edit items. I need to determine what item is receiving the action, hence looking for the click event, but the keypress determines the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets complicated when you assign listeners within listeners - you will need to make sure to remove the nested listener once the edit has been completed.

I would recommend storing the index of the item being edited into a variable and moving the editing listener so it is not nested. The editing listener can have a guard that will exit if there is no item being edited:

```js
if (!localStorage['todo-list']) {
    localStorage.setItem("todo-list", JSON.stringify([]));
}


function checkTodos() {
  var list = JSON.parse(localStorage['todo-list']);
  if (list.length == 0) {
    $('#notices').html(`<div class='card'>No list items exist yet. Use the input box on the left to add items.</div>`);
  } else {
    let html = "";
    list.forEach((todo, index) => {
      html += `<div id='item-${index}' class='card' data-index='${index}'>${todo}</div>`;
    });
    $("#todo-incomplete").empty().append(html);
    $('#notices').empty();
  }
}

function updateTodos(list) {
  $('#todo').val('');
  localStorage.setItem('todo-list', JSON.stringify(list));
  // each time we update the list, we need to display the updated list
  checkTodos();
}

function doConfirm(type = 'delete') {
  let message = type == 'delete' ? 'Do you confirm todo item deletion?' : 'Do you confirm todo item editing?';
  if (confirm(message)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const state = {
    editingIndex: null
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  let list;

  /* Gather info from the local storage database */
  if (localStorage) {
    list = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('todo-list') ? JSON.parse(localStorage['todo-list']) : [];
  }

  /* todo : display */
  checkTodos();

  /* todo : input */
  $(document).on('keydown', '#todo', (event) => {
    if (event.which === 13 && $(event.target).val() != "") {
      list.push($(event.target).val());
      updateTodos(list);
    }
  });
  /* todo : click events */
  $(document).on('click', '#todo-incomplete > .card', (event) => {
    console.log('click');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    /**
     * BELOW IS WHERE ALL THE PROBLEMS WITH STACKING CLICKS COME INTO PLAY
     */

    if (event.shiftKey) { // delete todo item
      if (doConfirm()) {
        list.splice($(event.target).attr('data-index'), 1);
        updateTodos(list);
      }
    } else if (event.altKey) { // edit todo item
      $(event.target).attr('contenteditable', true);
      state.editingIndex = $(event.target).data('index');
      /* $(document).on('keydown', event.target, (e) => {
        if (e.which === 13 && doConfirm('edit')) {
          $(event.target).removeAttr('contenteditable');
          list[$(event.target).attr('data-index')] = $(event.target).html();
          updateTodos(list);
        }
      }); */
    } else {
      // we do nothing.... yet!
      console.log(event.which);
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('keydown', '.card', (event) => {
    if (!state.editingIndex) { return; }

    if (event.which === 13 && doConfirm('edit')) {
      $('.card').eq(state.editingIndex).removeAttr('contenteditable');
      list[state.editingIndex] = $(event.target).html();
      state.editingIndex = null;
      updateTodos(list);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="todo" type="text">
<div id="notices"></div>
<div id="todo-incomplete"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliance! Thank you.